# What is the lifecycle of an Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, geolocation, ip-geolocation

I am not so clear on how the program in working in Android. I started working on Android for last two months and also I am a beginner in Java. So, I am trying my best to develop and learn. Here is the piece of code I implemented and I am not so clear how it works as per my requirement.

```
 activity{
    onCreate(){
          /* here i am using google maps api and trying to plot the current location*/                 
      OverlayItem overlayItem1 = new OverlayItem(ourLocation,"Our Location","Position");
         CustomPinpoint custom1 = new CustomPinpoint(d, Activity.this);
            custom1.insertPinpoint(overlayItem1);
            overlayList.add(custom1);               
                controller.animateTo(ourLocation);
        }
    private class TouchOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay{
          public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView map){
              onZoom();
         }
        }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){}
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
       case.X:
        getGPSPoints();//Here i will be getting some gps points from stored database 
         // and I would like to plot them all on the map. 
        TouchOverlay touchOverlay = new TouchOverlay();
    overlayList.add(touchOverlay);
    }
    onPause(){
            super.onPause();
    lm.removeUpdates(this);
    }
    onResume(){
            super.onResume();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(towers, 500, (float) 0.5, this);
    }
    onLocationChanged(Location l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    clearmap();
    lat = (int) (l.getLatitude()*1E6);
    longi = (int) (l.getLongitude()*1E6);
    GeoPoint ourLocation = new GeoPoint(lat, longi);
    CustomPinpoint custom = new CustomPinpoint(d, TrafficMapActivity.this);
            OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(ourLocation,"Our location","Position");
            custom.insertPinpoint(overlayItem);
            overlayList.add(custom);
        }
       }
```

My question is when will `onLocationChanged` method be called and also onTouchEvent method?

I have created a method to `getGPSPoints()` and I would like to plot the obtained points on the map. What my intention is its like google maps traffic layer. I should be continuously drawing when we drag the screen or for zoom in/out. For this I am using the same `getGPSPoints` method inside `onZoom()` method in `TouchOverlay` class.

But it is just drawing once when I first selected the option and for the first zoom in/out operation. If I need to draw the remaining I have to click again on the option as per the current implementation. How does this activity works and I should have it?

Comment: [Activity Life Cycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)

Answer (score 1):

Your `onCreate` method is called whenever the Android OS has to "create" your Activity.

This will happen on the initial load of your Activity, and also whenever the OS has destroyed your activity voluntarily or if you call the activity's `finish()` method.

The `onCreate` method is followed by another Activity method called `onStart`.

This will be called when the Activity is now visible to the user.

Regarding the `onLocationChanged` and `onTouchEvent` implementations, these two types of methods are executed by a listener that is set to the object.

For example, `onLocationChanged` will execute every time your map listener has determined the location has changed.

The `onTouchEvent` will execute any time your view has received a touch event from the user.

Your `onPause` and `onResume` methods are part of the Activity class, these methods are similar to `onCreate`, although they are called at different times.

Specifically, `onPause` is called whenever your Activity is not the front, focused view.

The `onResume` method is the opposite of `onPause` - it will be called when your Activity's view is now the focused view on the screen.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html

Comment: Ok. you mean onCreate will run only once when the app is launched?

Comment: No, it may also be called if you have called the finish() method or if the view has not been in focus and the VM destroys it for more memory.

Comment: Related to TouchOverlay  class I created can you please explain me the lifecycle of it? I need to overlay all the data for various touchevents.

Comment: Since your TouchOverlay class is an inner-class in your Activity's class, it will follow the same lifecycle as your Activity (i.e., your Activity is destroyed, so are its inner and nested classes)

Comment: But when I try to run my activity, TouchOverlay is being recognized but the zoom method is not called. I don't see why it is not running.

Comment: Looking deep into the code I have written, TouchOverlay is a being subclassed with overlay and when ever I select the option to display overlay it displays the overlay and its method onZoom if performed only for once. But my requirement is, the surface should be thereafter listening to further changes like zoom, hover the screen. That is my onTouchEvent should be continuously listening to the surface. How can I do that?

Comment: You may need to post more code.  From what I can see, all you're doing is creating an instance of your ``TouchOverlay`` class and then adding it to a list called ``overlayList``

Comment: Yes. On selecting the particular option I will be calling this overlay list instance of class which has zoom method.
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView map) {         int action = event.getAction();
              if (event.getAction() == 1 || event.getAction() == 2 || event.getAction() == 0) {
                if (lastZoomLevel == -1)
                  lastZoomLevel = map.getZoomLevel();
if (map.getZoomLevel() != lastZoomLevel) {
                    onZoom(map.getZoomLevel());
                    lastZoomLevel = map.getZoomLevel();}

Answer (score 0):

It's all in the diagram below (found on the dev website among other places ):

[image: Android Lifecycle]

Comment: hey Barak, can you please explain me with my context.